# Is it possible to get actual video link from embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

I tried to get video from an embedded iFrame, but JS is de-obfuscated, may there is an actual src link hidden in JS, I tried my best and couldn't de-obfuscate, if I click Play I can find the source, but I am fetching it with Curl, but cannot find the video link.. can someone guide me through right direction, so I can dig more - thanks

Basically there is an iFrame page, that loads external video link, which is hidden, if I open with curl with the same site referrer it doesn't show anything. I need to reach the final link.

Comment: um.. wherever this js is, treat it like a string and find jsString.indexOf('cutt.ly') and that should be around it somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a call on https://secure.xyz.com/response.php with the same query parameters as those you get from the redirected url. Also it needs `x-requested-with` http headers set :

```sh
curl 'https://secure.xyz.com/response.php?sid=XXXXX=&product=XXXXX' \
     -H "x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest"
```

An example in [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```py
import requests

url = "https://cutt.ly/xxxxx"

r = requests.get(url)
queryParams = r.url.split("?")[1]

r = requests.get(f"https://secure.xyz.com/response.php?{queryParams}",
    headers = {
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    })

print(r.json())
```

Comment: thanks, it worked with curl as well.. cheers

Comment: oh I just realized you posted his url in public, if possible please remove.. as example is great to understand, thanks